# Encounter problems while compiling kerTeX on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, porting, tex, building

I was trying to compile kerTeX on Mac OSX 10.9 and encountered some problem. I downloaded this [get_mk_install.sh](http://downloads.kergis.com/kertex/get_mk_install.sh) from the [project homepage](http://www.kergis.com/en/kertex.html) and fed it to `sh`, it worked very well at first for a moment but terminated suddenly, the error message does not make any sense to me:

```
#========== BUILDING sys/sh1/pkglib
sed -e 's!@@TARGETSHELL@@!/bin/sh!'\
                 -e '/^##PKG_SYS_DEPENDENT/r /Users/user/Temp/kertex/kertex_T/sys/sh1/pkglib/./unix.data' /Users/user/Temp/kertex/kertex_T/sys/sh1/pkglib/sh.data\
             | sed -e 's!@@SYS_FTPC@@!ftp!'\
                         -e 's!@@SYS_HTTPC@@!ftp!'\
      -e 's!@@SYS_SUDOING@@!sudo!'\
                         -e 's!@@SYS_ROOT_ID@@!0!' >pkglib.sh

#========== sys/sh1/pkglib DONE (50/50)
Programs that failed to build:
!mpware/sh1/mp2ps
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Can any one help on this, or point me to where solutions can be found.

My purpose is to port some TeX system to mobile platforms such as Android, iOS, etc., to compile TeX scripts locally. Is this the appropriate solution for my task? If there are ones that are better, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the mobile use case I created the [TeX--](https://github.com/bwoods/TeX--.git) project. Note that it produces DVI files, not PDFs.

> A TeX implementation in a single C++11 class.
>
> Based upon version 3.1415926 of tex.web. Minimal changes to the original sources were performed; preferring instead to leverage p2c’s configurability to manipulate the produced C source. The main goal was getting TeX’s massive number of symbols out of the global scope; making it easy to embed.
>
> Creation of the header file is done through the `tex.sh` shell script, so that it can be regenerated at any time. No manual clean-up or restructuring of the code has been done. Some *automated* transformations of the code are done in the shell script. Primarily to replace certain C constructs with C++ equivalents.

The `web/tex.hpp` file should be all you need. Feel free to open Github issues on the project.